# Apache on Windows, how are CGIs terminated on client disconnect?

Tags: c++, windows, apache, cgi

I have a CGI program (written in C++) that is started by Apache. It sends a long-running stream of data to the client. This works; the problem is that if the client disconnects, the CGI program does not notice this and keeps running until it is manually interrupted.

On Linux Apache sends a SIGPIPE that aborts the CGI program. But SIGPIPE does not exist on Windows. How does Apache tell the CGI program that it should stop?

The full setup is as follows: the client asks for a .BAT file, which then runs a .EXE file. Ideally I'd like to keep this setup, but I could call the .exe file directly if that is necessary. The C++ program writes its output to std::cout. I'm not seeing any errors writing to std::cout.